# how to find a substring from string using python

Tags: python

I need to find the count of substring present in a main string

```
String = "hello raj ajrrajarjra"
```

Substring can be the combination of 'r' 'a' 'j' characters
The substring can occur in any combination of those three characters

Comment: Hello @Rajesh, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please follow the guidelines on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please give some examples, and what you have tried so far and we will be happy to help.

Comment: What would be the expected result in the example you gave?

Comment: Use `count` , eg `'hello raj ajrrajarjra'.count('j')` is 4

Comment: I need the count of substring

Comment: The sub string can be any possible combination of r,a,j characters

Comment: I tried string.find("raj")

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This prints every combination of 'r', 'a' and 'j' , and how many times it occurs in `my_string`

```
from itertools import permutations

my_string = 'hello raj ajrrajarjra'
letters = [ 'r', 'a', 'j' ]
substrings = [ ''.join(sub) for l in range(0, len(letters)+1) for sub in permutations(letters, l) if len(sub) > 0 ]

for substr in substrings : 
    print('{0} : {1}'.format(substr, my_string.count(substr)))
```

Result

```
r : 5
a : 5
j : 4
ra : 3
rj : 1
ar : 1
aj : 3
jr : 2
ja : 1
raj : 2
rja : 0
arj : 1
ajr : 1
jra : 1
jar : 1
```